# Should I use JSONField over ForeignKey to store data?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm facing a dilemma, I'm creating a new product and I would not like to mess up the way I organise the informations in my database.

I have these two choices for my models, the first one would be to use foreign keys to link my them together.

```
Class Page(models.Model):
    data = JsonField()

Class Image(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
    data = JsonField()

Class Video(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
    data = JsonField()

etc...
```

The second is to keep everything in `Page`'s JSONField:

```
Class Page(models.Model):
    data = JsonField() # videos and pictures, etc... are stored here
```

Is one better than the other and why? This would be a huge help on the way I would organize my databases in the futur.

I thought maybe the second option could be slower since everytime something changes all the json would be overridden, but does it make a huge difference or is what I am saying false?

Comment: Putting everything in a JSONField obfuscates a lot of the functionality and isn't recommended. It makes it more difficult to validate your data since anything can be stored in the JSON. And it makes it more difficult to extend your models with custom methods (maybe a Video objects wants to be able to display its duration, in which case you'd want to define a `duration()` method on `Video`).

Comment: And by the way, where are you planning to store the actual binary blob of your `Image` and `Video`? I hope not in the `data` field, databases aren't good at that!

Comment: @dirkgroten This is just an example, but it doesn't have to be videos and image could be pizza and toppings, etc... mostly it's only texts with restriction of 155 characters

Comment: Django has a `URLField` type which could allow you to store the `link` as an explicit field. Again, this makes validation much easier, otherwise you have to validate it all yourself inside the JSON.

Comment: @dirkgroten but performance and scalability wise, which on makes more sense? I thought maybe the second option could be slower since everytime something changes all the json would be overridden, but does it make a huge difference?

Comment: Relational databases are optimised for JOIN between tables so in terms of performance and scalability you're better off using ForeignKeys. PostgreSQL's JSONField isn't that performant actually, don't use it to mimic a real non-relational db like mongo or cassandra. It's really meant for cases where you have some undetermined data to store, like serialised responses from external APIs or a serialised reference to a historical python object.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks for the help, you should post that as answer instead :)

Comment: And don't forget: readability, scalability (easy to apply changes) and maintainability of your source code is much much much more important on the long run than performance and scalability, when you start getting there, there are other ways to improve that.

Comment: @dirkgroten Indeed, I just thought that jsonfields are easier to modify than postgresql fields in the long term in case I have many users and a little change to the model could break the app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `JSONField` obfuscates the underlying data, making it difficult to write readable code and fully use Django's built-in ORM, validations and other niceties (`ModelForm`s for example). While it gives flexibility to save anything you want to the db (e.g. no need to migrate the db when adding new fields), it takes away the clarity of explicit fields and makes it easy to introduce errors later on.

For example, if you start saving a new key in your data and then try to access that key in your code, older objects won't have it and you might find your app crashing depending on which object you're accessing. That can't happen if you use a separate field.

I would always try to avoid it unless there's no other way.

Typically I use a JSONField in two cases:

- To save a response from 3rd party APIs (e.g. as an audit trail)
- To save references to archived objects (e.g. when the live products in my db change but I still have orders referencing the product).

If you use PostgreSQL, as a relational database, it's optimised to be super-performant on JOINs so using `ForeignKey`s is actually a good thing. Use `select_related` and `prefetch_related` in your code to optimise the number of queries made, but the queries themselves will scale well even for millions of entries.